# Compass a la USB

Tags: usb, sensors

I'm looking for a compass (the cardinal direction kind) sensor that I can connect via USB.  I'm willing to revert to an integrated circuit and Arduino or some such, but an off-the-shelf device is ideal.  Is there a product like this available?  Am I just searching for the wrong thing?

Comment: Sorry, but...we don't sell those here. Product recommendations/shopping suggestions are considered [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on SU.

Comment: These are usually called magnetometers now, you'll see them listed under smartphone features. They give the magnetic flux in all three dimensions, rather than the simpler data of old compasses. With a brief Google search I saw magnetometers as ICs or boards but nothing that connects over USB.

Comment: Dependent on your use case - the map applications like Delorme and others - used to come with USB GPS devices.  They can serve as compasses of a sort.

Comment: @Blackbeagle I've found something that I think will work, and heading seems like a reasonably available feature with gps over usb devices — you should add your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @moses I'm not asking for plugs, comparisons, or recommendations; a totally valid answer is that this feature is subsumed by X type of device and that's how everybody gets this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependent on your usage, map applications like Delorme and others used to come with a plug-in USB GPS devices. You could use them for compasses of a sort.